# how to take out values from other array

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove values from an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288148/how-to-remove-values-from-an-array-in-php)

I have this

```
$arr1 = array('orange','banana');
$arr2 = array('broccli','tomato','mixedvegies','orange','veg2');
```

how would I take complete $arr1 from $arr2 so that arr2 has

```
$arr2 = array('broccli','tomato','mixedvegies','veg2');
```

Answer (score 6):

```
array_diff($arr2, $arr1);
```

array_diff returns an array with all the elements *not* in the second (or third, fourth... optional args).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) for this:

```
$uniqueItems = array_diff($arr2, $arr1);
```