# Remove array value from given array PHP

Tags: php

I have first array like this:

```
["19","20","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32"]
```

and the second array:

```
["19","20"]
```

How i can remove value the first array with given second array?

value i need:

```
["25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32"]
```

Comment: This is `array_diff`

Comment: @rizier: better dupe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288148/how-to-remove-values-from-an-array-in-php?rq=1

Comment: ah very fast answer, thank you :)

Comment: @MarcB You can change it if you want. I will remember that dupe for the future.