# Take out every element after an array element has been found

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say I have an array that looks like this:

```
    array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");
```

How can I remove every value after banana. So the new array would contain orange and banana, everything after that should be gone.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove values from an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288148/how-to-remove-values-from-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must search for the value that you want (banana), get the key and then use array_slice to get part of the array using the key of the banana as the lenght.

Here is a code example.

```
$a = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");

$key = array_search('banana', $a);
$newArray  = array_slice($a,0,$key+1);

print_r($newArray);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Vidal it would be $key+1. They want to include the searched term as well.

Comment: And obviously won't work unless keys are 0 based and sequential `array(1=>"orange", 2=>"banana", 3=>"apple", 4=>"raspberry");`.  Probably use `array_values` on it.

Comment: that's true, it's not going to work for associative arrays, but he is not using or ask for a slice of an associative array.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function to pass array and what you want to search and split on.

```
function getArraySection($a, $str) {
  $key = array_search($str, $a);

  if ($key === false) return []; #return empty array since section wasn't found

  return array_slice($a, 0, $key+1);
}

var_dump(getArraySection($a, 'banana'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Here's the code:

```
$fruits = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");
# Cut fruits, from 0 take 2 elements
$new_array = array_slice($fruits, 0, 2);
print_r($new_array);
```